# Facebook like button on wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, post, facebook-like

Hello I have wordpress blog with facebook like button under each post. The problem is when I clicked like button it counts very well but it doesn't display that I liked this post on my facebook profile. Are there any errors in code? :

```
<iframe class="like-post" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;locale=en_US&amp;width=100&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=false&amp;height=21" style="float: left; border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;width:80px;" ></iframe>
```

Comment: How does the above code render out on the page? Does the <?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?> produce a valid url?

Comment: What does the link look like when PHP has done its thing?

Comment: It renders something like this: `https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blog.pl%2Flifestyle%2Fprzeczytales-to-na-kapslu-od-tymbarka-daj-spokoj-i-poczytaj-mrozka%2F`